# Trying to understand the PS Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus/Remove for Azure ADF

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-data-factory

[image]Every Time I try to run the below command I get Error response, as per the doc I gone through it says it belongs to [Az.DataFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2triggersubscriptionstatus?view=azps-3.8.0) module but still dont get how to run this script- no matter if the Modules updated and the PS updated I still cant get this script to run.

**Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus**

Script is actually used in Microsoft ADF devops configuration PS script

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

the release stucks @ this particular command in Azure devops

Comment: Check your script, see if there are old [`AzureRm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) commands in it? In other words, did you use `Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus` mixed with `AzureRm` module commands?

Comment: Try to restart your PowerShell session in VSCode. What you get if run command `Get-Module AzDataFactory` ?

Comment: Thanks guys, Im using Az powershell not AzureRM, and the module is alredy imported. and I still dont find anything on Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus